# Nullpointerexception on dispatchDraw with ViewPager in nested fragment with PageTransformer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm having a pretty nondescript bug in the Android app I'm working on. I have a fragment, which in turns contains a ViewPager that's backed by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The pager contains two fragments.

Whenever I try to add a PageTransformer (using the ones from the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), everything works fine until I try to navigate away from the fragment containing the viewpager (backpress or regular). The error I get is the following. I can't really trace what's causing it x_x. Code snippet of the pager construction at the bottom.

```
Process: edu.utcs.android, PID: 11728
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2946)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14476)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2171)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13370)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14476)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13370)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13365)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2959)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13365)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:870)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13365)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13365)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14476)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:381)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13370)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14190)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14476)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2324)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13370)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13412)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1577)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2282)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1022)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5708)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at de.robv.andro
```

Pager construction:

```
mAdapter = new LabPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mLabPosition);
```

I've tried rearranging some lines in case it was some sort of race condition, and also tried reversing the animation (the "false" boolean on the 3rd line), but no luck.

**EDIT**

With some trial and error, and some help from user2152081, I've gone with a hacky workaround by overriding the ViewPager class with my own, and wrapping the super call in draw() in a try/catch block.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        super.draw(canvas);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d("ViewPager", "Nullpointer skipped");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pandanomic it did solve my case as well.

Comment: Have you the same problem if you replaced getChildFragmentManager() by a getActivity.getFragmentManager(). I encountered the same issue if I used the getChildFragmentManager() but it disappear if I use the actvitiy fragmentManager. No idea if it can help but it solved my issue.

Comment: @JM.Pascal I did try that, but it caused other issues due to it trying to re-add those viewpager fragments if i left and came back to that fragment. A nested viewpager should get the childfragment manager, not the regular

Comment: I discoverted If you add your fragment with viewpager in the backstack you need to use childfragment manager.  But you can use the regular if this fragment is not add to backstack (and with retainInstance == false). It surprised me also ^^ but I have both configuration that works.

Comment: @JM.Pascal ahh good point. None the less, it did still crash for me when i tried that (i was using the backstack at the time i think, though I did change it later so there's a chance my memory is off). Glad you got it working though, hopefully helps anyone else that sees this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll answer here.

I ran into exactly the same issue. Looking at the source for ViewGroup, it was running through the children of the *android.support.v4.view.ViewPager* and hitting the NPE there. As you stated, removing the  page transformer worked, as did removing the PagerTabStrip for me. I'm looking at it right now, but it looks like some kind of incompatibility between the page transformer and the PagerTabStrip.

Specifically, when the ViewPager is asked to redraw itself, at the top of your stack trace:

```
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2946)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14476)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2171)
```

For me, at this point the ViewPager has only a single child - the PagerTabStrip. In dispatchDraw in ViewGroup, this is where the NPE pops up:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    final View child = children[getChildDrawingOrder(count, i)];
    if ((child.mViewFlags & VISIBILITY_MASK) == VISIBLE || child.getAnimation() != null) {
        more |= drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }
}
```

Where children[] contains the PagerTabStrip as it's 0th entry, for some reason, children[getChildDrawingOrder(count, i)] is evaluating to null.

```
getchildDrawingOrder(count, i)
```

is not overloaded in my implementation, so it just returns i. Its beyond me as to why this is evaluating to null - it certainly seems like it should return the PagerTabStrip, but it's not and it's generating the NPE when trying to access the children[0]'s members.

I have no solution for you, but hopefully this is similar to what you've run into. Let me know if you find out anything.

## *EDIT*

Not quite sure why, but replacing my ViewPager with this seems to have resolved the crash:

```
package ca.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class TestViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public TestViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TestViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
        return i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Overriding getChildDrawingOrder(...) fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Actually that didn't completely fixed the problem. Only the second (last) page in the viewpager would be clickable, and even if I clicked on the top page, it would still register clicks as if I was on the second page.

Doing this however in the custom viewpager class did fix everything. It's hacky as hell, but it works. I'll update my post with it

@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            super.draw(canvas);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.d("ViewPager", "Nullpointer skipped");
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah, it certainly doesn't seem like the way it's intended to be done, but I couldn't find anything other than your post describing the issue. Seems not that many people have run into it. If you come across a better solution, please let me know, as I'm using this solution right now.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! I've lost 2 days trying to solve this issue but thanks to you it's 90% solved. I've 2 fragments with 4 ViewPagers each, same logic like you, problem is 1st fragment gets it 4 ViewPagers correctly rendered but the 2nd fragment don't. They exist but I don't know why they are like "hidden". I can "scroll" the ViewPagers but I can't see them. Any idea why? Overriding the getChildDrawingOrder worked for me but I've Overrided the draw just in case... Thanks!