# dispatchDraw NullPointerException without any useful error message

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

when i use the the code from https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids implement some effect.sometimes it will happen crash.the message is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2911)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12841)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12890)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13640)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2912)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12841)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12890)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13640)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2912)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12841)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12890)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13640)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2912)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12841)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12890)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13640)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2912)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2247)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12846)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12890)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2567)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2236)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1211)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5039)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:922)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:689)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is no any useful message.I even use try catch block like this:

```
   try
    {
        configureEmiter(emiter, gravity);
        startEmiting(particlesPerSecond);
    }catch (NullPointerException e){

    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
```

but it does not work.
Is there any idea to resolve this problem? please help me, thanks very much.

Comment: add more logs:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 3733):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3197)

Comment: PS: i have used viewpager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038131/nullpointerexception-on-dispatchdraw-with-viewpager-in-nested-fragment-with-page check this, error is with viewpager

Comment: @Karan Mer， Thanks you for your answer,but the way can not resolve my problem. It still be crash sometimes. OMG~~~~~

Comment: try replacing your v4 jar with updated v4

Comment: @Karan， I have update my v4 to com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.and it does not work. I use the view pager with DepthPageTransformer. I have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560721/all-the-fragment-is-gone-when-used-depthpagetransformer. I think the crash and the fragment gone  have the same reason. But I don't know the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some wrong in my code.I have remove the view cause the problem.Thank you for your concern and answers.